# what is the difference between these two derivatives

Tags: derivatives

I don't understand this: We know that the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$. At the same time, it seems that the derivative of $y$ if $y=x^2$ is not $2x$ but $2x\times\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$. Can you explain me that please? What do I miss?

Comment: Ehm.. what? No if $y=x^2$, then the derivative of $y$ (with respect to $x$), also denoted $dy/dx$, is equal to $2x$. That is $dy/dx = 2x$.

Comment: @ergon Please try to be more clear when you write a question. If you are differentiating a variable you need to state which variable you are differentiating with __respect to__.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are confused about "[chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)".

Derivative of $y=x^2$ with respect to $x$ is $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2x$.

But suppose $f(x),g(x)$ are differentiable functions. then $[f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x))\times g'(x)$.

In those lines, if $y(x)=x^2$, and let $g(x)=x$. Then derivative of $y(g(x))$ with respect to $x$ is $\dfrac{dy(g(x))}{dx}=2x\dfrac{dg(x)}{dx}=2x\dfrac{dx}{dx}=2x$, which is a lot of hardwork to write, so we simply differentiate it without caring much about chain rule if $g(x)$ a constant function or $g(x)=x$

Comment: My last paragraph makes me doubt if the egg came first or the chicken. Anyway, let it be there in case it helps OP!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. If $y=x^2$, then $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$. But, the derivative of $y^2$ with respect to x is $2y\frac{dy}{dx}$ by the chain rule.

If you expand $\frac{d}{dx}y^2 = 2y\frac{dy}{dx}$, you get that $\frac{d}{dx}x^4=(2x^2)(2x)$, which you can see works perfectly using the Power Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very misleading but I will answer it both ways:

The chain rule for the derivative of a function of one variable is $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\times\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\tag{1}$$

So for your first case $y = x^2$, differentiate both sides with respect to $x$: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(y\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}
{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x^2\right)\tag{2}$$

using ($1$) for the left hand side of ($2$) $$\implies \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\left(y\right)}_{\color{#F80}{=1}}\times\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=2x$$

$$\implies \color{red}{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=2x}$$

However, if $x=y^2$ (which is what I think you're asking) use the chain rule ($1$) again:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(y^2\right) = {\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\left(y^2\right)}\times\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

$$\implies \color{blue}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(y^2\right) = 2y\times\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}}$$